# Change default datetime format when converting to string

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

When a datetime is automatically converted to a string it uses this undesired format:

```
mon dd yyyy hh:miAM
```

how can I change this default so it is a more typical format like:

```
yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss.mmm
```

Also, I don't want to have to explicitly use a cast/convert each time:

```
Convert(char(23),__date__,121)
```

I'd like to use CONCAT() without wrapping a convert around the datetimes.  I generally keep appending a string variable by dumping in local variables, etc. as my stored procedures process.  In the CATCH, I write this string out, but whenever datetime values are concatenated in, it uses the undesired format.

Sample code:

```
Declare @Now  datetime=GETDATE()
       ,@Temp varchar(100)

SET @Temp=CONCAT('It is now: ',@now)

PRINT @Temp -----------------------It is now: Feb  8 2019  1:45PM
SELECT @Now -----------------------2019-02-08 13:45:05.247
Print @Now ------------------------Feb  8 2019  1:45PM
Print Convert(char(23),@Now,121)---2019-02-08 13:45:05.247
```

Output:

```
It is now: Feb  8 2019  1:45PM

-----------------------
2019-02-08 13:45:05.247

(1 row affected)

Feb  8 2019  1:45PM
2019-02-08 13:45:05.247
```

Comment: I'm afraid, if you do not want to rely on implicit settings (which would produce rather random output on different systems), there will be no way around explicit format specifications...

Comment: The only point-of-control I know of for this is the locale settings on the server.

Comment: This seems more like something you should be doing in your presentation layer.

Comment: If you declare the variable as `datetime2(0)` instead of `datetime` is the output more to your liking? Or `PRINT SYSDATETIME()` instead of `PRINT GETDATE()`

Comment: @Larnu, as stated in the question, this is for internal use via a catch block of a stored procedure.

Comment: @MartinSmith, Yes, datetime2 works better.  It has more precision than we need.  I'm not sure If I can use that, we have thousands of tables and procedures that use datetime. nice idea though.

Comment: There really is no solid word around here. If you want date string representations in a certain way, you have to format them the way you want them.

Comment: you can always create your own function to format once, and then reference the function name.

Comment: @Greg, I have a function now that takes a sql_variant parameter and it outputs a string ready for concatenation.  It formats dates, handles nulls and numbers.  it works great for everything by max length strings. I'd like to get away from using that  home grown function and use the built in CONCAT() function, but this ugly date format is getting in the way.

Comment: Isnt that what my code below does?

Comment: @Greg, No, my function handles strings, datetimes, numbers, etc, without CONCAT(), I can't see why I should use both.  I just want a quick easy way to dump some variables in to a string just in case control goes to the CATCH block.

Answer (score 0):

If you are writing new code, and you are ok with creating objects to support your desired format, then you can do it in a function.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fn_NewDate() 
RETURNS varchar(23) 
AS 
BEGIN
    RETURN(CONVERT(VARCHAR(23), GETDATE(), 121));
END
GO

Declare @Now varchar(23) = dbo.fn_NewDate()
       ,@Temp varchar(100);

SET @Temp=CONCAT('It is now: ', @now)
print @Temp;
```

Result:

```
It is now: 2019-02-08 12:43:38.980
```

Comment: I have a function now that takes a sql_variant parameter and it outputs a string ready for concatenation. It formats dates, handles nulls and numbers. it works great for everything by max length strings. I'd like to get away from using that home grown function and use the built in CONCAT() function, but this ugly date format is getting in the way.